# Searching a Binary Tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am a bit lost in JavaScript. I have this structure:

```
{
    "value": 5,
    "children": [{
        "value": 18,
        "children": [{
            "value": 27,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "value": 4,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "value": 2,
        "children": []
    }]
}
```

How can I get the highest value in the tree using JavaScript?

Comment: what height value you want to know?

Comment: What does this have to do with _"Binary"_?

Comment: in this example, your desired end result would be - 27? or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: well, maybe i am mistaken to use the binary(just used this based on my searches, i have no background in dealing with this). -Cerbrus,

Comment: i guess 27, since the way i look at it, it is the highest value, -webkit

Comment: @Cerbrus: A [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) is a tree structure in which each node can have at most two children.

Comment: @user2641282: To notify a user you've replied, use `@`, not `-`.

Comment: Do you only want the value `27`, or the actual element that has the highest value? (In this case: `{"value":27, "children":[]}`)
@T.J.Crowder: ooooh, okay.

Comment: Highest value of Parent or Childern?

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, i was instructed to look for the highest value, and have a javascript code to display through an alert message. Hope things are still clear, i really have no idea with json and trees, but i did some searches still not clear

Comment: @user2641282: You're almost certainly not using JSON (unless you're reading text from a file or URL). That's just JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it was saved on a .json format, but still, how can i display the highest value via alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case you'd might want to use this:

```
var baseObject = {
    "value": 5,
    "children": [{
        "value": 18,
        "children": [{
            "value": 27,
            "children": []
        }, {
            "value": 4,
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "value": 2,
        "children": []
    }]
};

function getHighestValue(obj) {
    var res = obj.value;
    for(var i in obj.children) {
        res = Math.max(res, getHighestValue(obj.children[i]));
    }
    return res;
}

alert(getHighestValue(baseObject));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qc9R4/1/

Comment: thank you, this will help, ill just read on this.

Comment: Herp derp, I'm blind o.O This works perfectly, +1.

Answer (score 0):

if understand you correct should look something like this.

```
var highestValue = JSONresponse.value;

HighVal(JSONresponse);

function HighVal(JSON) 
{ 
   if(highestValue < JSON.value)
   {
     highestValue = JSON.value
   }
   for(i=0;i<JSON.children.lenght;i++)
   {
     HighVal(JSON.children[i]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this, if your object tree pattern is the same,

Stringify object and do regular expression to fetch all the integer values of this pattern "value: {n}" and then find the max value.

```
  var jsono = {
        "value": 5,
        "children": [{
            "value": 18,
            "children": [{
                "value": 27,
                "children": []
            }, {
                "value": 4,
                "children": []
            }]
        }, {
            "value": 2,
            "children": []
        }]
    }
    var maxvalue;
    JSON.stringify(jsono).match(/\"value\":\s*(\d+)/g).map(function(value){ return value.match(/(\d+)/g).map(function(value){ maxvalue =  Math.max(maxvalue || 0,value);});});
    alert(maxvalue);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6R9p3/1/

Answer (score -1):

I won't write the code for you, but basically, it's the same with any other language.

You traverse through every right child until you know that it's the end node.

How to use JavaScript to access JSON?

```
var tree = 
{
  parent : [
    {
      //child1 details
    },
    {
      //child2 details
    },
  ]
}
```

For JSON key access, use `tree.<key> (dot)` or `tree['key']`. In this case, `tree.parent` or `tree["parent"]`.

For Array access, use indices. Since `parent` is an array, you can access the children by `tree.parent[0]` or `tree['parent'][0]`.

I prefer the dot method though, to distinguish visually JSONs and arrays.

**Also**, you need something to distinguish a right child and a left child. You can either make it a convention to make the right child as the `[0]` index in the array, or you can add another value per node that says that its right or left.

Comment: thank you, things are getting clear now

Comment: You're going to have to mention recursion, there...

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, recursion is needed here